# How can I not require tqdm to be installed?

Tags: python, tqdm

I'd like to use tqdm in my script but not require others to use it if they haven't installed it.

I've found this:

```
try:
    import tqdm
except ImportError:
    tqdm = None
```

But I'm not sure how to use `tqdm==None` with this:

```
with tqdm.tqdm(total=totalSize) as pbar:
```

Where `totalSize` is the file size (or sum of file sizes when looping over multiple files).

Comment: you would basically have to write a class that mocks all the features of your tqdm context manager that does something neutral, i.e. maybe return the iterator it gets passed, or simply a range object when handling totalsize...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from tqdm's [documentation](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#manual) and my try/except logic, I have this working:

```
try:
    import tqdm
except ImportError:
    tqdm = None

if (tqdm == None):
    pbar = None
else:
    pbar = tqdm.tqdm(total=totalSize)

#... inside the loop processing my file[s]...
if (pbar):
    pbar.update(len(line))
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I usually do it is by adding the following shim:

```
try:
    from tqdm import tqdm
except ImportError:
    def tqdm(iterator, *args, **kwargs):
        return iterator
```

Now, you can just always use tqdm without having to worry about whether or not it exists, as the fallback will pass through the thing you're iterating over, ignoring all tqdm related options.

```
for item in tqdm(items):
    action(item)
```

Admittedly your usage (using `with`) isn't compatible with this approach - but I'll leave this here for people using it in a for loop like I usually use it.

Comment: Genius. So simple, yet effective. Thanks!